# Find references on the paley wiener theorem on the multiplicatif group R*?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I’m preparing my thesis on the paley wiener theorem and I’m stuck at the beginning, can you please provide some references for Fourier analysis on the multiplicatif groupe R* and on the paley wiener theorem there?